# Bootstrap Modal not working(nothing happens when button clicked)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have importaed javascript into my layout template:

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

I have the following bootstrap modal triggered by a button

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Did I forget to do something here? I have never done a bootstrap modal before but this should open a modal upon hitting the button correct? I thought it was because perhaps I was missing bootstrap javascript but I imported it from cloudflare min file and still doesn't do anything. What I am missing?

Comment: Did you forget to include jQuery?

Comment: ohhh hmm how would i do that?

Comment: I am using minified version libraries from here: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4

Comment: Just add the Jquery before callin the bootstrap js    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: If you check the console there are likely errors that can be helpful here.

Comment: https://jquery.com/download/  grab a cdn link from there and add a script reference to your page, above the bootstrap script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a `script` tag for the bootstrap JS cdn not a `link` tag like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also make sure you are using `jQuery`

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap JavaScript is written in a script tag, not a link one. The link one is for CSS.

Yours:

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

It should be:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You also need to include jQuery like this

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

**Otherwise your code is just fine!**